# Validating client-side data input using a pattern

Tags: javascript, validation, client-side

I am currently working on a project whereby data can be added into a database via a website. Currently I have managed to configure it so that the form accepts title, postcode, vehicle reg and ID number.

Javascript validation is working fine for these entries, with the exception of ID number. All ID numbers are a specific format (2 numbers followed by a . followed by 4 numbers).

I cannot seem to work out how to define the pattern.

Due to the size of my code, I have not posted the full code here (all is validating except this ID validation), but I've provided a snip of the 'if' statement below which I'm trying to come up with.

```
if (inputElement.id == "wid") {
    pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;
    feedback = "Only 2 numbers followed by a . followed by 4 numbers are 
permitted";
```

I know that the pattern isn't correct here but I have searched for hours trying to locate some easy to explain guidance and cannot find anything which appears to be relevant.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Where is your dot? Where are your digits? You have a space and letters. Also you do not test the ID against your regexp. Have a look at https://regex101.com/ to test your code - it is REALLY trivial https://regex101.com/r/utkPGg/1

Comment: [Look at some examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out something like https://regex101.com/ to test you regexes, and see an explanation of it.

I think your pattern should be this: `/^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}$/`.
The first part (`[0-9]{2}`) makes sure that the id starts with 2 digits, then a dot `\.` (which must be escaped, because it means "every character" otherwise) and then 4 digits `[0-9]{4}`

Comment: I think the validation must first check the length of the string to make sure it is 7, and the apply the regex. Otherwise something like 12.3456foo will match too

Comment: Thank you - this has worked for me after a few tweaks! Never heard of regex, really useful resource - thanks again!